# libgit2 and index locking for read-only queries

Tags: concurrency, locking, race-condition, libgit2

Does libgit2 obtain an index lock like the git itself does when obtaining information about a repository (current branch, modified files, anything that doesn't lead to changes)?

I ran into an issue today where an attempt to squash a single commit into a single other commit (via rebase -i) failed git removes that lock between rewriting commits. I had the project open in an IDE which picked up a file change and reloaded the directory in reaction, which includes obtaining certain git observables; a race condition ensued and my rebase was the victim.
Edit: I'm not yet entirely certain which observables, but those must include the current branch (shown in the project manager) and which files are known by git (to en/disable items in the git context menu). A priori those can all be obtained from a write-protected clone don't have a crucial need for write-locking the clone.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=404515

Comment: Definitely need more information here.  Yes, libgit2 takes a lock on the index when it's writing it and *no* there's no way to turn that off.  But you can disable index _writes_ on some operations like diff by disabling `GIT_DIFF_UPDATE_INDEX`.

Comment: Meaning I can check for other GIT*_UPDATE_INDEX flags?

Comment: Well, maybe?  There's also `GIT_STATUS_OPT_NO_REFRESH` that you can set.  But what command are you running?